# Enable Keyboard in QT application that is started with systemd

Tags: linux, debian, systemd, qt

I am trying to get hardware keyboard support to work in my QT 4.8.6 application for the Beaglebone Green that is running Debain. The file system does not have any desktop so linux boots into a console that shows tty1 at the  top.

I created a systemd service in /lib/systemd/system/ to have my app start on bootup. The application starts but I don't get any hardware keyboard input. Here are some things I tried:

1. Manually start the application from the tty1 console:
   Result: Hardware keyboard works in my app
2. Manually start the application from a serial console ttyS1:
   Result: No Hardware keyboard

My systemd service file looks like:

```
[Unit]
Description=MyApp Startup script Service
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/usr/local/bin/myAppdir
ExecStart= /bin/sh myAppStartupScript
SyslogIdentifier=MyApp

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I tried using the above service to start nano, but I can't tell if nano ever starts. After the system boots up, I don't see nano running. I also don't see it in the process list when I run ps command. The above service does start my qt app. I was trying to find out if I can get hardware keyboard support in nano by using the above service.

It seems like I am not using systemd properly. Does anyone know what I am maybe doing wrong?

Comment: You need your app to start in the active terminal. Redirect input and output to the default terminal (`/dev/tty1`) in `myAppStartupScript` by adding `exec </dev/tty1 >/dev/tty1 2>/dev/tty1` near the beginning of the script (it does not exec anything, but redirects standard input, output, and error all from/to `/dev/tty1`), and optionally ensuring that terminal is the active one using `chvt 1`. (The latter is necessary if you use e.g. `/dev/tty7`, which allows you to retain e.g. login/getty in the first six virtual terminals.)